# MySQL value don't show in picture name

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code to upload a picture. When the picture is uploaded, the user can crop it. Then, the picture is called with the `$new_name`. The only problem I have, is that in the `$new_name`, `$_GET['MomentEvent']` never appear in the picture name. But when I echo it, it appear normally. So, how could I make it appear in `$new_name` also?

For information, `MomentEvent` refer to a unique key for each new page created. So when a user upload a picture, it only show the picture on the page with the good `MomentEvent`.

**Edit:** it looks like the problem come from this line: `echo $new_name."?".time();`, cause when I try to just echo `$_GET['MomentEvent']`, nothing happen.

**Edit 2:** It look like the problem come from `if(isset($_GET['t']) and $_GET['t'] == "ajax")`, cause with the last echo, it's outside, and all work, but with the echo inside, nothing work. But I still have no clue on what's wrong...

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
     $session_id=$_SESSION['id']; // Or Session ID
         $actual_image_name = time().substr($txt, 5).".".$ext;
         $t_width = 450; // Maximum thumbnail width
         $t_height = 150; // Maximum thumbnail height
              $new_name = "$actual_image_name".$_GET['MomentEvent'].".jpg"; // Thumbnail image name
              $path = "images/";

         if(isset($_GET['t']) and $_GET['t'] == "ajax")
         {

         extract($_GET);
             $ratio = ($t_width/$w); 
             $nw = ceil($w * $ratio);
             $nh = ceil($h * $ratio);
             $nimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
             $im_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$img);
             imagecopyresampled($nimg,$im_src,0,0,$x1,$y1,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
             imagejpeg($nimg,$path.$new_name,90);
         mysql_query("UPDATE users_event SET image_small='$new_name' WHERE MomentEvent='".$_GET['MomentEvent']."'");
         echo $new_name."?".time();
         exit;
         }
     echo $new_name;
 ?>
```

Comment: Why do you assign $_GET['MomentEvent'] to $MomentEvent and then never use it?

Comment: Actually I forgot to delete it...!

Comment: So if you echo this:  $new_name = "$actual_image_name".$_GET['MomentEvent'].".jpg"; what do you get?

Comment: The same as echo $new_name;

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can you give a sample expected output and what you're actually getting?

Comment: What I'm waiting for:
/images/1380242047.(MOMENT_EVENT HERE).jpg                   

What I have:
/images/1380242047.(NOTHING).jpg

Comment: So you echo $_GET['MomentEvent'] and the moment event echos?

Comment: Yes, it echo only at the end of the code, but not in the $new_name part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use extract.  It is bad practice to use it generally, but especially on a _get variable...it opens you up to a DOS attack where someone can flood your query string with hundreds of unneeded variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Just reference the associative array items individually.